# Excel 2007 : paste from clipboard to visible rows only

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

What I want to do is to copy multiple lines from a .txt file and paste it into an excel sheet that have hidden rows. Each line on my text file is correlated to the same **visible** row on the excel sheet.

When I paste the information from the txt file into the sheet, it take into account the hidden lines... half of my data is trapped in the hidden lines.

I've tried the F5 manipulation to only select the visible cells (for the destination) and it's not working ("copied zones and pasted zones have different sizes").

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?  I'm having trouble with this as well.

Comment: Unfortunately... [No](http://superuser.com/help/badges/38/tumbleweed?userid=356750).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the proper way, but it works for me.
I paste the txt lines in to a new sheet or workbook of excel, starting from `B1`. In my filtered sheet showing only the visible data I select all cells in the column and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+, to only select the visible ones. 
I type in `=ROW("cell to the left" ie: A7)`, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, to enter it across all cells. Then I copy them and paste them as values in the new sheet to the left of my data. It should only paste the visible ones.
Afterwards I go back to original sheet and edit the formula to be `=VLOOKUP(ROW(A7),NEWSHEET!A:B,2,FALSE)` to get my data from column `B`.